# Descending Order and Placement of Null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a column such as ID containing integers in descending order with one null value
ex.

```
ID
====
20
19
18
...
2
1
null

select id from mytable order by id desc
```

I need this to be ordered descending but null on top:

```
ID
====
null
20
19
18
...
2
1
```

The null is a result of a prior

```
union all
```

and needs to be there.
I had a few ideas, such as create an artificial large number.
Just want to see what your guys can come up with.
Have fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` to force the `NULL`s first. This is supported by SQL Server.

```
SELECT
  id
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  id DESC
```

It works by deriving a "column" on which to sort that holds a 0 for `NULL` and 1 for everything else.  The 0 sorts ahead of the 1.  Then, we add the rest of the `ORDER BY` column chain to continue sorting, so adding `id DESC` forces the remaining rows (those with our derived 1) to sort in descending order by id.

Comment: That would place it at the bottom of the list, i need it at the top, thanks though!.. I could set the id to something like 9999

Comment: @HarHaHu I did a bit of editing while you were commenting. See the current version, which should get what you want.

Comment: @Michael Thanks so much, it worked wonderfully.  I was getting an error initially because CASE does not work on a UNION ALL Result so i set my UNION as a derived table and then sort accordingly.  Please explain how this works.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify your DBMS, but if it is ANSI compliant you can do the following:

```
ORDER BY id NULLS FIRST
```

(This works on Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, H2, HSQLDB, Derby, Firebird)

Comment: Sorry, fantastic option but not supported in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Normally it would help to know what particular DBMS you're using but in general there are several options.

`CASE` is usually supported in the `ORDER BY` so you can do something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 DESC, ID DESC
```

or you could do as you suggested and use a large number

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(ID, 2147483647) DESC --or whatever your maxint is
```

The latter may be more efficient, take a look at the query plan.